# Ошибка в рассказе "Пеппи Длинныйчулок"?

Tags: литература

Вот цитата из текста:

> Учительница решила  сегодня  больше  не  заниматься арифметикой.  Она
>   подумала,  что,  быть может,  чтение у  Пеппи пойдет лучше.  Поэтому
>   она вынула из  шкафа картонку,  на которой был нарисован ежик.  Под
>   рисунком стояла большая буква "П".
>   - Ну,  Пеппи,  сейчас я покажу тебе интересную вещь. Это П-е-е-жик. А буква, которая изображена вот тут, называется "П".

Что за "П-е-е-жик"???

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вообще-то в переводном первоисточнике эта фраза звучит как

> Поэтому она вынула из шкафа картонку, на которой был нарисован ежик.
>   Под рисунком стояла большая буква "Ё". - Ну, Пеппи, сейчас я покажу
>   тебе интересную вещь. Это Ё-ё-ё-жик. А буква, которая изображена вот
>   тут, называется "Ё"

[books.google.ru](https://books.google.ru/books?id=pDAtAgAAQBAJ&pg=PT36&lpg=PT36&dq=%D0%A3%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0+%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0+%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8F+%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B5+%D0%BD%D0%B5+%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F+%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9.+%D0%9E%D0%BD%D0%B0+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0,+%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE,+%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C+%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82,+%D1%87%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5+%D1%83+%D0%9F%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BF%D0%B8+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82+%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D1%88%D0%B5&source=bl&ots=95n8qJEV4_&sig=BzY-yeVDSH6NeNHAOg6lkUM2QQI&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwii7oSUu6zLAhWGE5oKHco6DXUQ6AEIIjAB#v=onepage&q=%D0%A3%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0%20%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0%20%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8F%20%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B5%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9.%20%D0%9E%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%2C%20%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%2C%20%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82%2C%20%D1%87%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D1%83%20%D0%9F%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BF%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D1%88%D0%B5&f=false)

Где Вы взяли Ваш текст?

Comment: [Здесь](http://lib.ru/LINDGREN/peppi1.txt).

Comment: Так это же оцифровка. К ним и все вопросы. Вот к этой нражданке: ***OCR: Елена Байрашева***.